# view.frame change on orientation change - no change

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, swiftui

I am developing an app with SwiftUI - using some UIKit components - that has Picture in Picture, and I am trying to keep the picture in a specific corner of the screen when rotating the device. In order to do this I need to change the position of the frame on the view, and so I have registered with `UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification` and when this notification comes through I change the view frame in the `UIViewController` like this:

```
@objc func onViewDidTransition() {
        view.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200)
        self.cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.landscapeRight
    }
```

However, this doesn't seem to do anything. The frame doesn't change at all. As though the `UIView` has kept the old frame and changing to the new `CGRect` does nothing. When I inspect the object with `view.frame.` there is no option for `x` or `y`, as though these properties are not changeable after initialisation. Is this right? Is there no way for me to change the position of the frame?

EDIT: Code.

The frame is setup in the `setup()` function of `CustomCameraController`

```
func setup() {
            view.frame = CGRect(x: 225, y: 0, width: 150, height: 150)
```

And later it is modified in `onViewDidTransition()`

```
@objc func onViewDidTransition() {
        view.frame = CGRect(x: 662, y: 0, width: 150, height: 150)
```

This should put the picture in the top right corner (iphone x) when transitioned to landscape, but it doesn't. The image stays at 200 pt from the left corner.

Minimum reproducible ContentView code

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

struct CustomCameraPhotoView: View {

    @State private var image: Image?
    @State private var showingCustomCamera = false
    @State private var showImagePicker = false
    @State private var inputImage: UIImage?
    @State private var url: URL?

    var body: some View {
        CustomCameraView(image: self.$inputImage)
    }
}

struct CustomCameraView: View {

    @Binding var image: UIImage?
    @State var didTapCapture: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack() {

            CustomCameraRepresentable(image: self.$image, didTapCapture: $didTapCapture)
        }
    }

}

struct CustomCameraRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Binding var image: UIImage?
    @Binding var didTapCapture: Bool

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> CustomCameraController {
        let controller = CustomCameraController()
        controller.delegate = context.coordinator
        return controller
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ cameraViewController: CustomCameraController, context: Context) {

        if(self.didTapCapture) {
            cameraViewController.didTapRecord()
        }
    }
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
        let parent: CustomCameraRepresentable

        init(_ parent: CustomCameraRepresentable) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {

            parent.didTapCapture = false

            if let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() {
                parent.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            }
            parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
}

class CustomCameraController: UIViewController {

    var image: UIImage?

    var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var backCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var frontCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var currentCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var photoOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput?
    var cameraPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

    //DELEGATE
    var delegate: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate?

    func didTapRecord() {

        let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
        photoOutput?.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: delegate!)

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setup()
    }
    func setup() {
        view.frame = CGRect(x: 225, y: 0, width: 150, height: 150)
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 40
        view.layer.masksToBounds = true
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        setupCaptureSession()
        setupDevice()
        setupInputOutput()
        setupPreviewLayer()
        startRunningCaptureSession()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onViewDidTransition), name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func onViewDidTransition() {
        view.frame = CGRect(x: 662, y: 0, width: 150, height: 150)
        self.cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.landscapeRight
        //UIDevice.current.orientation
    }

    func setupCaptureSession() {
        let cameraMediaType = AVMediaType.video
        let cameraAuthorizationStatus = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: cameraMediaType)

        switch cameraAuthorizationStatus {
        case .denied: break
        case .authorized: break
        case .restricted: break

        case .notDetermined:
            // Prompting user for the permission to use the camera.
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: cameraMediaType) { granted in
                if granted {
                    print("Granted access to \(cameraMediaType)")
                } else {
                    print("Denied access to \(cameraMediaType)")
                }
            }
        @unknown default:
            break
        }
        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.iFrame1280x720
    }

    func setupDevice() {
        let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera],
                                                                      mediaType: AVMediaType.video,
                                                                      position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.front)
        for device in deviceDiscoverySession.devices {

            switch device.position {
            case AVCaptureDevice.Position.front:
                self.frontCamera = device
            case AVCaptureDevice.Position.back:
                self.backCamera = device
            default:
                break
            }
        }

        self.currentCamera = self.frontCamera
    }


    func setupInputOutput() {
        do {

            let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: currentCamera!)
            captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
            photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
            photoOutput?.setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray([AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.hevc])], completionHandler: nil)
            captureSession.addOutput(photoOutput!)

        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

    }
    func setupPreviewLayer()
    {
        self.cameraPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        self.cameraPreviewLayer?.cornerRadius = 40
        self.cameraPreviewLayer?.masksToBounds = true
        self.cameraPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        self.cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
        self.cameraPreviewLayer?.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(cameraPreviewLayer!, at: 0)

    }
    func startRunningCaptureSession(){
        captureSession.startRunning()
    }
}
```

Comment: Any minimal reproducible code?

Comment: @Asperi I will prepare something and edit my question

Comment: @Asperi I've added something focused which should demonstrate the problem with not too much code.

Answer (score 0):

Dumb mistake. I was modifying the frame of the View:

```
view.frame = CGRect(x: 662, y: 0, width: 150, height: 150)
```

When I should have been looking at the frame of the camera preview layer:

```
self.cameraPreviewLayer?.frame = self.view.frame
```

I have changed the code to modify the camera preview layer and leave the view frame alone, and now it works.

```
self.cameraPreviewLayer?.frame = CGRect(x: 662, y: 0, width: 150, height: 150)
```